# Dynamodb query on date attribute for greater and less than operator

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I have table created in Dynamodb with below details

```
class OrderStatusIndex(GlobalSecondaryIndex):
    class Meta:
        index_name = 'OrderStatusIndex'
        read_capacity_units = 2
        write_capacity_units = 1
        projection = AllProjection()
    order_status = NumberAttribute(hash_key=True)
    created_on = UnicodeAttribute(range_key=True)


class Order(Model):

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'order'
        host = 'http://localhost:8000'
        read_capacity_units = 2
        write_capacity_units = 1

    order_id = NumberAttribute(hash_key=True)
    order_status = NumberAttribute(hash_key=True)
    created_on = UnicodeAttribute(range_key=True)
    order_status_index = OrderStatusIndex()
```

now i wanted to query based on order status which got in particular date
if i do the mysql query this will be like below

```
select *from order where order_status = 0 and created_on >= start_date and created_on <=end_date
```

is there any way same thing we can achieve in Dynamodb using pynamodb

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for order_item in Order.scan(Order.order_status == 0 & (Order.created_on >= start_date) & (Order.created_on <= end_date)):
    print(order_item)
```

The link to `pynamodb` API doc:

http://pynamodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pynamodb.models.Model.scan

You can refer to the following links to know how to use conditional expressions on a `pynamodb` query.

https://pynamodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/batch.html#query-filters

https://pynamodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/conditional.html#condition-expressions

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is very costly and not a good way as it scans the entire table. You should look into indexes.